# Can I create a proprietary application using Qt?

Tags: qt, proprietary, license, qt-creator

I am using Qt4 to build an application and for some reason I want to keep it proprietary. Qt4 is released under LGPL, does that force me to release the code to my application. I ask this question because I am finding it difficult to understand the LGPL license.

Comment: As far as I know, Qt relatively recently underwent licensing changes that allowed you to use it in close source commercial products. *It didn't used to be okay, which is why a great many folks used to prefer GTK*

Comment: @aking1012: Not that recent. Mathematica has been using Qt for a few years at least.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail IIRC it had to do with cost of licensing previously.  January 2009 or so is when it went LGPL according to this blog post: http://successfulsoftware.net/2009/01/14/qt-to-be-available-for-free-under-lgpl/ for the decade previous it was pay to be used commercially.

Comment: So you all are saying I can use it to make my own commercial product but the catch is I need to have the LGPL Licence with my binary?

Comment: Indeed. Note also that the binary can not have Qt statically linked, as that would mean it is considered a derivative work instead of something using it - which would mean that you would have to either open-source your app, or pay for the proprietary-licensed Qt version.  
  

Dynamic linking and including the LGPL is all you need to do.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes.

"The main difference between the GPL and the LGPL is that the latter allows the work to be linked with (in the case of a library, 'used by') a non-(L)GPLed program, regardless of whether it is free software or proprietary software.

Source:[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License)

Comment: This is a great answer. To make it even better, you can try to expand with more examples.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @user64152's answer I have to add one more thing. If along with proprietary you also intend to make a commercial product and modify the Qt libraries, you have to buy the Qt Commercial License in order to be able to sell your product.

Comment: This is not true. LGPL (which Qt is released) Allows commercial/closed source applications as long as you do not modify the qt libraries or if you do making them available to the public. But just the LGPL'd libraries.

Comment: Yes, I didn't express myself clear enough. Will add this to my answert. Thanks!